# Debugger stops at JsonConvert.DeserializeObject

Tags: c#, json.net

I have a class 'FixedSizeStack' as shown below.

```
public class FixedSizeStack
    {
        public int top;
        public string[] stack;
        public int maxSize;

        public FixedSizeStack(int size)
        {
            maxSize = size;
            stack = new string[size];
        }    

    }
```

In my program, the debugger stops at the below line and it doesn't proceed further

```
EntityStack = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FixedSizeStack>(cacheManager.Get("XYZ"))
```

soon the CPU percentage reaches 100%. What could be the root cause?

Comment: Possibly an infinite loop. What is the expected value of `cacheManager.Get("XYZ")`? How is `cacheManager` implemented?

Comment: Put the two calls in *separate* lines. Right now you have no way of knowing what's causing that 100% CPU - deserialization or `cacheManager.Get` ?

Comment: Besides, given that almost all machines are multicore now, the only way to get 100% CPU is to flood all cores. `DeserializeObject` is *not* a parallel operation. Most likely `cacheManager.Get` causes a race condition forcing all cores to hit 100%. A *blocking* or locking operation can do that nicely, since blocking typically starts with a spinwait. That's not a bug of the runtime either - locks are supposed to be short lived. Rescheduling a thread is very expensive so it makes perfect sense to start with a spinwait before putting the thread to sleep

Comment: The solution is to *not* block. Use eg a `ConcurrentDictionary` instead of a standard dictionary with locking.